# Calculate next date without saturday

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to calculate a delivery date where the truck is standing still on saturdays (but not sundays)
If the leadtime is two days and I order on friday, the shipment should arrive on monday (sunday+monday). The following works great but it excludes sunday:

```
df['LEV'] = dat + df['Leadtime'].map(pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay)
```

I want to do something like this. But its not working:

```
df['LEV'] = dat + df['Leadtime'].map(pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sun'))
```

Where:

```
2021-05-14 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Thank you

EDIT:
Small example:

```
from datetime import datetime
DatToday = datetime.fromisoformat('2022-01-13')
data = {'Article': ['A1', 'A2'], 'LeadTime': [2, 6], 'DateToday': 
[DatToday,DatToday]}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  


df['Delivery_Day'] = DatToday + df['LeadTime'].map(pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay)
```

Current result:

```
Article    LeadTime  DateToday     Delivery_Day
0     A1    2        2022-01-13    2022-01-17
1     A2    6        2022-01-13    2022-01-21
```

Wanted result:

```
Article    LeadTime  DateToday     Delivery_Day
0     A1    2        2022-01-13    2022-01-16
1     A2    6        2022-01-13    2022-01-20
```

I.e., BusinessDay without sunday.

Error msg:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, 
convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
4198             else:
4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, 
convert=convert_dtype)
4201 
4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\offsets.pyx in 
pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.BaseOffset.__call__()

pandas\_libs\tslibs\offsets.pyx in 
pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.apply_wraps.wrapper()

ApplyTypeError:
```

Comment: you say it's "not working" what output are you getting? and for what inputs?

Comment: Yes of course. I'm getting ApplyTypeError:. Input LeadTime is integer.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Hi!
 I have updated my original post with a small runnable example :)

Comment: Please provide the error *and* traceback *in* your question, not in a comment.

Comment: "If the leadtime is two days and I order on friday, the shipment should arrive on monday (saturday+monday)": what happened to Sunday? And why is Saturday included if the trucks stand still? Why is Friday not included (order day), while the delivery day is included?

Comment: Sorry. It should be sundays are always included but not saturday. The order is placed at the end of the day and the truck arrives late on the delivery day. So that is why.

Comment: No sorry it is not truncated, that is all that I get from Jupyter.

Comment: I just tried the example and your not-working code: the error traceback is indeed truncated, and ends with an "open" colon. How odd. Feels like a bug in Pandas (the error traceback itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **multiply** your [`CustomBusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay.html) by the number of days:

```
cbd = pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sun')

df['Delivery_Day'] = DatToday + df['LeadTime'] * cbd
```

output:

```
  Article  LeadTime  DateToday Delivery_Day
0      A1         2 2022-01-13   2022-01-16
1      A2         6 2022-01-13   2022-01-20
```

Comment: @fsl you could also use a `lambda` to set the weekmask and pass the LeadTime to it through `map`, but I think this is just easier this way ;)